# How do I make my labels in tkinter centralize?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically the question. I have my layout of my top row of the GUI exactly as I want it apart from the fact that I need the title to be in the center with gameturns to the left and gamerounds to the right. I searched the answer to the question myself and only found answers that basically said ".grid does it by default" which I didn't really get. I've tried doing sticky="nsew" on my .grid configuration, but they still won't go to the center. Am I misunderstanding how sticky works? How do I make everything on my first row be in the center?

```
#game GUI goes here

maingame = tk.Tk()
maingame.title("Louise's Card Game")
maingame.geometry("600x350")
maingame.resizable(0, 0)

#top row labels
gameturns = tk.Label(maingame, text="{}'s Turn".format(currentTurn), font=("Courier", 10), padx=10, pady=10)
gametitle = tk.Label(maingame, text="Louise's Card Game", font=("Courier", 15), padx=10, pady=10)
gamerounds = tk.Label(maingame, text=("Round {}".format(currentRound)), font=("Courier", 10), padx=10, pady=10)

#top row positionings
gameturns.grid(row=0, column=0)
gametitle.grid(row=0, column=1)
gamerounds.grid(row=0, column=2)

    
maingame.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `maingame.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)`. That will force all of the widgets to expand to fill the whole width. Also add back in the `sticky="news"` to all of the `.grid(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the three labels in a frame and use `.pack()` on the frame:

```py
...
frame = tk.Frame(maingame)
frame.pack()

# put top row labels in the frame
gameturns = tk.Label(frame, text="{}'s Turn".format(currentTurn), font=("Courier", 10), padx=10, pady=10)
gametitle = tk.Label(frame, text="Louise's Card Game", font=("Courier", 15), padx=10, pady=10)
gamerounds = tk.Label(frame, text=("Round {}".format(currentRound)), font=("Courier", 10), padx=10, pady=10)

#top row positionings
gameturns.grid(row=0, column=0)
gametitle.grid(row=0, column=1)
gamerounds.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Then the three labels will be put in the top center of the window.

Note that if `grid()` is used in other widgets inside `maingame` window, you can use back `grid()` on the frame.

---

If you still want to put the three labels inside `maingame` using `grid()`, try:

```py
maingame.columnconfigure((0,2), weight=1, uniform=1)

#top row labels
gameturns = tk.Label(maingame, text="{}'s Turn".format(currentTurn), font=("Courier", 10), padx=10, pady=10)
gametitle = tk.Label(maingame, text="Louise's Card Game", font=("Courier", 15), padx=10, pady=10)
gamerounds = tk.Label(maingame, text=("Round {}".format(currentRound)), font=("Courier", 10), padx=10, pady=10)

#top row positionings
gameturns.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
gametitle.grid(row=0, column=1)
gamerounds.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='w')
```

Comment: Would there be a way to use the frames AND .grid()? I feel like it would be more organized if I used frames and I'm now realizing that .pack() is most certainly not ideal for what I need to put on my gui later.

Comment: Nevermind ignore the previous comment, I just put the padding to a very high amount and it worked like I wanted (I needed one label and the left and one on the right)